# Sencha Touch, one store to be used by a list and a dataview display?

Tags: mobile, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, store

So I implemented a dataview and a list format card to display my json in store. I am trying to get the two view to share one store, since the data are the same. However the way i am doing it is not really working, if I only have Dataview or List it works fine. When I have both call the store, it will stop working... please help!

Dataview:

```
Ext.define('Sencha.view.hoardboard.HoardList', {
   extend: 'Ext.DataView',
   xtype: "hoardlist",
   requires: ['Ext.XTemplate'],
   config: {

                flex:1,
                scrollable: true,
                store: 'Plist',   
                baseCls: 'columns',

                itemTpl: '<div class=pin><img src={image}><div style="padding-top: 10px; padding-left: 20px; padding-right:20px">{name}<br>{brand}</div></div>'

   }
});
```

List view

```
Ext.define('Sencha.view.hoardboard.HoardList2', {
   extend: 'Ext.List',
   xtype: "hoardlist2",

   config: {
     flex:1,
     scrollable: true,
     store: 'Plist',   
     grouped: true,
     itemTpl: '{name}'
   }
});
```

Model

```
Ext.define('Sencha.model.HoardList', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        config: {
            fields: [
                {
                    name: 'name',
                    type: 'string'
                }, 
                {
                    name: 'image',
                    type: 'string'
                },
                {
                    name: 'type',
                    type: 'string'
                },
                {
                    name: 'brand',
                    type: 'string'
                }
                , 
                {
                    name: 'color',
                    type: 'string'
                },
                 {
                    name: 'description',
                    type: 'string'
                }

            ]

        }
    });
```

Store

```
Ext.define('Sencha.store.HoardList',{
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    storeId: 'Plist',
    model:'Sencha.model.HoardList',
    title: 'My Collection',
    autoLoad: true,
    sorters: 'name',
    grouper: {
        groupFn: function(record) {
            return record.get('name')[0];
        }
    },
    proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url : 'products.json',
            reader: {type: 'json', rootProperty:'products'}

        }

});
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking when you're using Sencha framework you don't share one store object between several visual controls.

If you want to use same store in two places you need to clone it and have two separate store objects.